# Android Studio: Error:/android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.4/lib/plugins/gradle-diagnostics-2.4.jar (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've just installed Android Studio 1.3 into my Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit). I created a new project and after finishing the process Android Studio shows **"Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed"**.

I found same type of questions in Stackoverflow but any of the solution didn't fit for me. I couldn't figure out the problem.

Here are some screenshots:

1. After creating a new project it shows the following message:
   [image]
2. When I opened the **gradle-wrapper.properties** file,I found as following:
   [image]
3. When I checked the directory "**android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.4/lib/plugins/**" I found the file "**gradle-diagnostics-2.4.jar**".
   [image]
4. Here is the log file - http://pastebin.com/QdXxCVc6

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: btw: your path is also different:
/home/imran/android-studio/gradle...
vs
/home/imran/ANDROID/android-studio/gradle...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I had the same problem today when I upgraded from Android Studio 1.4 to 1.5. After some googling and checking stackoverflow threads I managed to found a solution by following these steps:-

1. Create a new project and if that new project gets created successfully
2. Open the gradle-wrapper.properties file
3. Check the following line

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip

4. Take the version (in this example it's gradle-2.8-all.zip)
5. Update the same version number in the gradle-wrapper.properties file where the error is encountered
6. Do a gradle sync

This worked for me!

Comment: Nice! I didn't even need to create a new project. I already had my current project open in Android Studio, so in the project navigator I expanded the **gradle** folder, then I expanded the **wrapper** folder, then I double-clicked the **gradle-wrapper.properties** file, then in the **distributionUrl** line I simply changed the **gradle-2.4-all.zip** to **gradle-2.8-all.zip**, then I clicked "try again" to re-sync, and it worked!

Comment: Thanks LargeGlasses for your comments. Yes the idea here is just get the number from a project which is clean built after upgrade then take the correct version.

Comment: Thanks! Had the same problem when I upgraded AS from 1.4 to 1.5

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. That fixed my issue.

Answer (score 5):

this is not really an answer, but since i have not enough reputation to post a comment... anyway:

I just downloaded and installed android studio 1.3 on Mac OS. but i installed it on an EXTERNAL harddrive, both android studio and android sdk.

but gradle is still looking for an absolute default-path (/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/.../gradle-diagnostics-2.4.jar). maybe it could help you or somebody else to track down the error.

Comment: This is the right answer.  I initially opened Android Studio on my Mac from the Downloads folder.  Once I realized that, I closed it, moved it to Applications, and reopened it... but now Gradle is looking for everything in the location from which it was originally run... annoying...

Comment: I fixed the same issue by killing/restarting the Gradle daemon

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same error when I placed Android Studio into different directory.

The problem was solved by clicking `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`.